# Julia, perform substitution with on a probability basis

Tags: arrays, replace, julia, probability

I'm working with an array from a 3d array, and with lots of previous help here, got a very nice simple elegant solution :

```
## Reset 44 and 33 to 4 and 3 respectively
replace!(@view(Pop[end, :, 1]), 33=>3, 44=>4)
```

Now if I wanted to do the replacement on a probability basis, where I would supply the probability, can I do it in one line or do I need to write a function to interrogate the small array, and then loop through and do the substitutions based on the probability?  So for example if I wanted to replace 33=>3 with a probability of 0.7, so the sub is made on 70% of occurrences of 33, and replace 44=>4 with a different probability, eg 0.85 how would I write this?  Thx. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution, which is pretty efficient, only a few times slower than a deterministic `replace!`

```
function rreplace!(xs, args...)
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(xs)
        val = xs[i]
        for tup in args
            if val == tup[1][1]
                rand(tup[2]) && (xs[i] = tup[1][2])
                break
            end
        end
    end
    return xs
end
```

You can call it like this:

```
rreplace!(xs, (33=>3, Bernoulli(0.7)), (44=>4, Bernoulli(0.85)))
```

You could of course use other distributions aside from `Bernoulli`, as long as they return either `true` or `false`.

In your particular question, it would be

```
rreplace!(@view(Pop[end, :, 1]), (33=>3, Bernoulli(0.7)), (44=>4, Bernoulli(0.85)))
```